# Is the section tag appropiate for grouping form elements?

Tags: html, forms, semantics

I'm currently using p tags to surround form groupings (e.g. label, input and error message)...

p tags are what I've used for years but I'm having a bit of an issue as **p tags cannot contains divs etc**... so I'm considering using the 'section' tag to break up the form "sections" :)...

I'm look for some feedback if u guys think the use of this tag in this context is semantically/functionally appropriate... Forms for me as a web dev are 90% of my day so Really appreciate your thoughts and feedback :)

FYI (though inconsequential) I'm using Laravel Form for the examples!

**Before**

```
<p>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="{{ Form::form_value('first_name', $user) }}">
    <span class="error_message">{{ $errors->first('first_name') }}</span>
</p>

<p>
    <label>Surame</label>
    <input type="text" name="surname" value="{{ Form::form_value('surname', $user) }}">
    <span class="error_message">{{ $errors->first('surname') }}</span>
</p>
```

**After**

```
<section>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="{{ Form::form_value('first_name', $user) }}">
    <span class="error_message">{{ $errors->first('first_name') }}</span>
</section>

<section>
    <label>Surame</label>
    <input type="text" name="surname" value="{{ Form::form_value('surname', $user) }}">
    <span class="error_message">{{ $errors->first('surname') }}</span>
</section>
```

Thanks for your feedback [image: smile]

Comment: Why do you need an element around the label, input, span triples at all? What is the additional information that you are trying to convey?

Comment: I don't know why Bill is using an element around his "triples", but many frameworks like Bootstrap require one for styling purposes. I came here looking for a non-generic element I can use here, in fact.

Answer (score 3):

The [`section` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/sections.html#the-section-element) *can* be appropriate for grouping form elements, but certainly not for every input+label group. It’s a sectioning content element, which means that each `section` could be listed in [the document’s outline](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/sections.html#creating-an-outline). This is most likely not what you want.

A good case for `section` could be *very* long/complex forms, where each section possibly contains multiple [`fieldset` elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/sec-forms.html#the-fieldset-element). A rule of thumb for `section` use in general:

- you should use `section` if you provide a heading (`h1`-`h6`) for the content;
- you could use `section` if it would be appropriate to provide a heading for the content, but you don’t for some reason.

The [`p` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) is appropriate for grouping one or more input+label groups, as the second snippet in [example 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/grouping-content.html#example-d5e88398) shows. As you want to include possible error messages, using a (meaningless) `div` element for the group, with `p` elements as children, seems to be appropriate:

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="">
  </p>
  <p class="error_message"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `<section>` is the correct semantics to be using.  You could use `<fieldset>`, but I think that's for multiple inputs or you could possibly surround everything in a `<label>`.

e.g.

```
<label>
  First Name
  <input type="text" name="surname" value="{{ Form::form_value('surname', $user) }}">
  <span class="error_message">{{ $errors->first('surname') }}</span>
</label>
```

Otherwise, a `<p>` tag is perfectly fine, there's not much semantics to a form anyway.

Comment: But a paragraph surely can't be appropriate as these are not paragraphs... + label has to be the most unappropriate wrap ever although twitter bootstrap advocates it... form section -> <section> ???

Comment: I would personally use `<fieldset>`, though it might not be the most pretty, you can style it.  Your form probably has a broader semantic meaning than individual inputs, and a `<fieldset>` could convey that.  For structure, `<p> <section> <fieldset>` or even `<div>` works.  Here's the W3C wiki for fieldset and section.  http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/fieldset http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/section

Comment: If you have _multiple_ input/label element groups that are related, use `fieldset` otherwise, just use `div` or `li`.