# Can I put footer in navbar?

Tags: html, navbar, footer, nav, semantic-markup

I received designs for one project and client wants footer placed in sidebar which is main navigation. Is it correct to have structure like this? I mean from design part it looks good, but from code it looks weird.

```
<nav class="Navbar">
    <div class="Navbar-content">
        <!-- some stuff -->
    </div>
    <footer class="Footer">
        <!-- footers content -->
    </footer>
</nav
```

In w3 there is no exact rule which would forbid nesting footer in navbar.
https://www.w3.org/html/wiki/Elements/footer

Also the w3 validator doesn't recognize it as any kind of error, so I guess it's okay?

Comment: you will have footer in the bottom of the page as well, o why do you need `footer` tag specifically ?

Comment: Yes, the footer will still be placed at bottom thats no probem. Why do I need footer tag? Because it's correct html5 semantic and good for SEO, if I am not mistaken     EDIT: there will be only footer in sidebar

Comment: Well, it's good for SEO but it's not goot for SEO to have `footer` inside `nav`, more, it's not good to have 2 footer tags(it should be only one footer for a page)

Comment: if you are doing this for style reuse just use `Footer` class and not `footer` tag for adding styles; make it: `<div class="Footer>"`

Comment: I read (here: https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_footer.asp ) that you can have several footer tags

Comment: however u answred the question with saying that its not good to have footer inside nav, can you prove with some documentation please? its not that I dont trust you, I just couldnt find it and want to know more, thank you a lot

Comment: I guess there is no rule to not do this but it's unnatural(from my perspective). You can always use `nav` inside `footer` because `nav` basically represent **a set of navigation links;** but as `w3schools` stress **The <nav> element is intended only for major block of navigation links.**

Comment: Oh yeah, so basicaly your presumptions have same origin as my question, it just feels weird right? I guess I will go with it for now but would really welcome some more specified documentation

Comment: More or less, if you read carefully [Definition and usage](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_footer.asp) you will understand that there is no use for footer in a `nav`

Comment: Also from a SEO perspective, this html5 tags should help a crawler not confuse it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a `footer` element in a `nav` element. But it would represent the footer for that navigation, not the footer for the whole page.

**For a footer that applies to the whole page**, you have to place the `footer` element so that its nearest section parent is the `body` element. This means it can’t be a descendant of `section`/`article`/`nav`/`aside` nor of a sectioning root element other than `body` (`blockquote`, `figure` etc.). [See an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44998964/1591669)

If you want to show the navigation and the footer in a sidebar, you can use a `div` element for the sidebar:

```html
<body>

  <h1>…</h1>

  <div class="sidebar">
    <nav><!-- site-wide navigation --></nav>
    <footer><!-- site-wide footer --></footer>
  </div>

</body>
```